# mysql not inserting [&](AND) character

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, variables, character-encoding

I have an ajax script that will automatically send data to php so I can store it in mysql.  The script works fine except for something.  I can insert data to mysql but if the data contain an (&)[and] character, the data before the [&] will be stored and not the data after the [&].
Here is an example:
my data is : ----> 'this is a cat & a dog'.
Mysql will store "this is a cat" and ignore '& a dog'
Here is my code:  It not with pdo or mysqli.  I will change it soon!

```
<?php 
//connect to db
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
//select db
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

//get post variables from ajax
$link = $_POST['var1'];
$name = $_POST['var2'];
$size = $_POST['var2'];
$cat = $_POST['var4'];




//safe from sql injections
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$size = mysql_real_escape_string($size);
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);




//verify url existance
if (!preg_match("(^https://example\.com(.*))", $link)) {
    //not valid url
    mysql_close($con);
    exit();
}

//check if result already exist
$check = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM links WHERE  link = '{$link}';");

if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {
    // insert if not exist

    $sql="INSERT INTO links (link, name, size, category) VALUES ('$link','$name','$size','$cat')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_close($con);
}



?>
```

Comment: Read. Learn. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Have you output a sample query and run it against that database directly to see how the results compare?

Comment: @SecurityMatt He is at least escaping the input data, which is better than can be said for 50% of the MySQL-related PHP in StackOverflow questions.

Comment: a direct query in the database works without problem

Comment: mysql functions deprecated. Try [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a problem with anything on the server side, but rather how the request is made on the client.  You didn't show us that, though.  You need to use `encodeURIComponent` on the string with the ampersand that is part of the ajax request or else the `&` will be considered a separate parameter.  This is decoded automatically on the PHP side.